# Помогите, не могу разобраться

Tags: c++, циклы, for

мне надо вывести только четные числа, а выводет некорректно.

```
int f;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> f;
        int ff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> ff;
        int fff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> fff;
        int ffff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> ffff;
        int fffff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> fffff;
        int ffffff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> ffffff;
        int fffffff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> fffffff;
        int ffffffff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> ffffffff;
        int fffffffff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> fffffffff;
        int ffffffffff;cout << "Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî:"; cin >> ffffffffff;
        int gotika[10] = {f,ff,fff,ffff,fffff,ffffff,fffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffffff};
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (gotika[i] != 0)
            {
                cout << gotika[i];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что вы *отлично* проиллюстрировали, как **не надо** именовать переменные, запутавшись в количестве `f` и два раза в инициализации массива повторив `ffffffff`...

Затем вы объявили массив из **10** элементов, корректно (ну, если не считать недописанного девятого `f`, где оно нужно) инициализировали, а затем зачем-то решили вывести **11** элементов массива. Когда тянешь из кошелька больше, чем в нем есть - это, как правило, завершается плохо...